# Bash use diff to calculate similarity between two strings

Tags: bash

i try to calculate the similarity with bash through the "diff" command.

```
#!/bin/bash

# I get the email user
EMAILUSER=`info.sh -c user | grep @ | cut -d: -f1`


for ACCOUNT in $EMAILUSER ; do 

echo -e ""
echo -e "Validating pass from ${ACCOUNT}"
echo -e ""

# Compare Words 
WORDS=`cat words.txt`

# I Get password from all email accounts
PASS=`info.sh -c user | grep @ | cut -d: -f2`

for PASSWD in $PASS ; do

maxlen=${#PASSWD}
diffs=0
[[ ${#PASSWD} -gt $maxlen ]] && maxlen=${#WORDS}
    for((i=0; i < maxlen; i++))
do
  [[ ${PASSWDB:i:1} == ${WORDS:i:1} ]] || ((++diffs))
WORDS="${WORDS,,}"
PASS="${PASSWD,,}"
  done
  echo $((100 * diffs / maxlen))
    done
done

exit 0
```

The comparison works but I have an error in why I always compare all the passwords with the string value `$WORD`.

```
bash email_pass_check.sh

Validating password user@domain

62
55
62
62
62
62
38
45
62
62
41
62
62
62
41
```

In the variable `$EMAIL` I get the list of all email accounts and in the variable `$PASS` i get the list of all password from the email account.

I need this

```
Validating password user@domain

50

Validating password user2@domain

10

Validating password user3@domain

20
```

I don't know how to run the for command to be able to compare each password with the value of the WORD variable.

I don't know if I'll explain myself well.

Comment: Don't see what the problem here is. You asked it to output percentage difference, and it's done that (one out of four characters--`t/T`--is different; that's the `25` that was printed to the console). If you want to print the characters that are different, just do that from within the `for` loop.

Comment: `I don't know how to make it detect capital letters` "detect" in what way? Right now your algorithm "detects" the upper/lower case difference between letter in two strings.

Comment: An example input pair with your expected output and an explanation of how the actual output differs would make this question much more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to do a case-insensitive comparison. To do so, simply convert both input strings `s1` and `s2` to lowercase before doing the comparison. Insert the following in front of your loop:

```
s1="${s1,,}"
s2="${s2,,}"
```

However, with this approach the locale decides which letter variants are equal. For instance, the lowercase variant of `I` is `i` in most locales, but `ı` for Turkish. You can adapt the locale for your whole script using `export LC_ALL=tr_TR.UTF-8` or locally using subshells as in

```
s1="$(LC_ALL=tr_TR.UTF-8; echo "${s1,,}")"
...
```

Comment: Great help. In case the String contains numbers, example `s1 = Test and s2 = Test123`, how can I also detect this?

Comment: As already pointed out in the comments to your question, you have to specify what you mean by *"`detect this`"*. If you really want to *detect* numbers, use `grep -q '[0-9]' <<< someString` or `[[ someString =~ [0-9] ]]`. However, I'm pretty sure that is not what you want.

Comment: I am doing this in order to detect those users who have assigned a password similar to the username or domain, although I have applied security when creating passwords, systems with insecure passwords have remained. My idea is to run a cron where it compares the password with other commonly used strings and tells me the similarity percentage. It is understood? my English is not that good.

Comment: Your explanation of the big picture and your English are good. However, my question remains unanswered: What do you want to do with numbers inside `s1` and `s2`? Please make a concrete example, for instance *"`for s1=a1 or s2=b2 I want to show an error message because numbers are forbidden`"* or *"`I want to ignore numbers, that is, for s1=a1 and s2=a the difference should be 0%`"*. **By the way:** I would write a PAM module (similar to pam_cracklib) instead of running a cron job. Also, I'm a bit concerned that your cron job apparently can read the plain text passwords.

Comment: Speaking of PAM: [pam_cracklib](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_cracklib.html) probably covers your use case already. There is even an explicit option to check whether the password contains something related to the username.

Comment: Hello friends, I already updated the application can you help me

Comment: I had not understood the answer. Sorry for the inconvenience, I will correctly explain the problem

Comment: modified the publication with as much information as possible